# Almost done with my Tic Tac Toe game. Where and how would I add an error message if someone inputs a non-number (1-9) and asks to enter a new input?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, valueerror

I am making a tic-tac-toe game in Python. I am almost done but I am still missing adding a message that a number from 1 to 9 was not entered and to try again. What would I use to add that message and where?

I am using repl.it to test my code. The game takes turns asking the player X and player O to add a number to choose a square on the graph to where they want to play their X or O. It tells who won and asks if they want to play again.

Thank you!

```
#Implementation of Two Player Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python.

''' We will make the board using dictionary 
    in which keys will be the location(i.e : top-left,mid-right,etc.)
    and initialliy it's values will be empty space and then after every move 
    we will change the value according to player's choice of move. '''

theBoard = {'7': ' ' , '8': ' ' , '9': ' ' ,
            '4': ' ' , '5': ' ' , '6': ' ' ,
            '1': ' ' , '2': ' ' , '3': ' ' }

board_keys = []

for key in theBoard:
    board_keys.append(key)

''' We will have to print the updated board after every move in the game and 
    thus we will make a function in which we'll define the printBoard function
    so that we can easily print the board everytime by calling this function. '''

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['7'] + '|' + board['8'] + '|' + board['9'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['4'] + '|' + board['5'] + '|' + board['6'])
    print('-+-+-')
    print(board['1'] + '|' + board['2'] + '|' + board['3'])

# Now we'll write the main function which has all the gameplay functionality.
def game():

    turn = 'X'
    count = 0


    for i in range(10):
        printBoard(theBoard)
        print("It's your turn, " + turn + ". Enter a number from 1 to 9 based on your numeric keyboard?")

        move = input()        

        if theBoard[move] == ' ':
            theBoard[move] = turn
            count += 1
        else:
            print("That place is already filled.\nMove to which place?")
            continue

        # Now we will check if player X or O has won,for every move after 5 moves. 
        if count >= 5:
            if theBoard['7'] == theBoard['8'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # across the top
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")                
                break
            elif theBoard['4'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['6'] != ' ': # across the middle
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break
            elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['2'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # across the bottom
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break
            elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['4'] == theBoard['7'] != ' ': # down the left side
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break
            elif theBoard['2'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['8'] != ' ': # down the middle
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break
            elif theBoard['3'] == theBoard['6'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # down the right side
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break 
            elif theBoard['7'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['3'] != ' ': # diagonal
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break
            elif theBoard['1'] == theBoard['5'] == theBoard['9'] != ' ': # diagonal
                printBoard(theBoard)
                print("\nGame Over.\n")                
                print(" **** " +turn + " won. ****")
                break 

        # If neither X nor O wins and the board is full, we'll declare the result as 'tie'.
        if count == 9:
            print("\nGame Over.\n")                
            print("It's a Tie!!")

        # Now we have to change the player after every move.
        if turn =='X':
            turn = 'O'
        else:
            turn = 'X'        
    
    # Now we will ask if player wants to restart the game or not.
    restart = input("Do want to play Again?(y/n)")
    if restart == "y" or restart == "Y":  
        for key in board_keys:
            theBoard[key] = " "

        game()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Comment: @Brian: Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @martineau [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Just add a simple while loop after move = input() while move not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
           print("Please enter a number between 1 and 9")
           move = input()

Comment: @martineau sure, it probably wasn't the best phrasing.